# android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

Tags: android, android-support-design

When i connect Tablayout and view pager it causes my app to crash i'm using the latest version of the android support library. How else would i go about making an app with sliding tabs.

```
 ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
                new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Comment: seems like `pager` is the `id` of the `ViewPager` which you are trying to cast into a `TabLayout`.

Comment: Why are you using same id `R.id.pager` for both `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`.

Comment: i get this when i use the id for TabLayout http://i58.tinypic.com/2i20i02.png

Comment: What is your parent Layout??.. CoordinatorLayout ?? FrameLayout??

Comment: please post the corresponding layout files, log exception and onCreate method, or it's impossible to guess what happened.

Comment: my parent layout is a coordinator Layout

Comment: ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);                                       TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.pager);

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you are using the same `id` to find the `ViewPager` and the `TabLayout.`

```
   ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

In your layout check the right id for the TabLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the layout by changing the width of CoordinatorLayout to wrap_content and changing the width and height of view pager to wrap_content. I also gave TabLayout its own id.